# Linked css does not work for button

Tags: php, html, css

my problem is that the css which is located in a different file does not work for a button.

My button:

```
echo "<p><i><input type='button' id='register' value='register'/></i></p>";
```

My css:

```
#register {
    background: red;
}

#register:hover{
    background: black;
}
```

For some reason the `:hover` works perfectly but the `#register` not at all

Thank you all.

Comment: But it does! Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JzSL8/

Comment: you most likely have another `#register` defined, do a search for it

Comment: Is your #register getting it's color from your file? Can you change it from red in the referenced file?

Comment: If it's a specificity problem, try `input#register` instead, which might override a plain `#register` definition elsewhere.

Comment: did not work.. but thanks for the interest!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Bm9E4/

please make sure that your `link href` is correctly put in your header.

If you are using a relative path, please make sure it links correctly.

Alternatively you can use an absolute path for linking to your css

[Check here the differences](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm)

Most probably your #register  is overwritten by another one . Please give more code ( or the order in which the css is loading ) or search through other or the same css

Answer (score 0):

CSS works on specificity. The more specific you are, the higher priority that style takes.
For example:

```
HTML
<div id="myDiv"></div>

CSS
#myDiv {
    height: 200px;
}

div#myDiv {
    height: 0;
}
```

In this example the height will be set to 0 because div#myDiv is more specific. You can run in to this problem a lot if you're not careful.